# Why is Java MongoDB Driver 3.0.2 missing bulk feature

Tags: java, mongodb

BulkWriteOperation builder = coll.initializeOrderedBulkOperation();

initializeOrderedBulkOperation() is missing in version 3.0.2, but it is found in version 2.13.2 ?

Is the method in 3.0.2 under a different name ?

I am using maven for the mongo dependency

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
        <!--Or version 3.0.2-->
        <version>2.13.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bulk operations are supported.  Take a look at the [reference guide](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.0/driver/getting-started/quick-tour/#bulk-operations) for examples.